# How to make UIButton.Configuration highlight appearance match that of system buttons

Tags: ios, uikit, uibutton

I'm modernizing my app and updating `UIButton`s to use `UIButton.Configuration`. I switched a system button to the default plain configuration style but was surprised to find the button highlight state is barely noticeable. When you tap down on a traditional system button, its alpha decreases a lot to indicate it’s being pressed, so it’s easy to know when you release the touch this button will be triggered. Unfortunately with the plain button configuration, the highlight state is hard to see because the appearance barely changes. Is there a way to make this highlight behave like all the other buttons such as `UIBarButtonItem`s?

```
let oldButton = UIButton(type: .system)
oldButton.setTitle("System Button", for: .normal)
oldButton.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 150, height: 30)
view.addSubview(oldButton)

let newButton = UIButton(configuration: {
    var config = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
    config.title = "Plain Button"
    return config
}())
newButton.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 150, width: 150, height: 30)
view.addSubview(newButton)
```

This is the highlight state of the system button:

[image]

This is the highlight state of the plain button:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to implement `configurationUpdateHandler` like:

```
newButton.configurationUpdateHandler = { sender in
  switch sender.state {
    case .highlighted:
      sender.alpha = 0.6
    case .normal:
      sender.alpha = 1
    case .selected:
      sender.alpha = 0.6
    default:
      break
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to not be a simple alpha change, at least in dark mode it's a different transformation that changes the color itself. There's no animation either it immediately changes alpha while the system button has different timing on touch drag exit/enter.